# Data extension has field with space, how to get reference it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a field in my data extension with a space like this:

[image]

I want to reference it in my email like this:

```
VAR @test
SET @test=Conversion Status
%%= v(@test) =%%
```

But an error pops up. What is the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you still want to reference it as variable, it'd be something like this:

```
%%[
VAR @test
SET @test = [Conversion Status]
]%%
<br>Conversion Status: %%=v(@test)=%%
```

or better:

```
%%[
VAR @test
SET @test = AttributeValue("Conversion Status")
]%%
<br>Conversion Status: %%=v(@test)=%%
```

Reference:

- [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just trying to pull it into the html of the email w/o modification...you should just need the value in the HTML:

```
<h1>Conversion Status</h1>
<p>%%Conversion Status%%</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone don't want to create a variable, you can do it like below.

```
%%=v([Conversion Status])=%%
```

OR

```
%%=v(AttributeValue("Conversion Status"))=%%
```